# import web app as a chrome app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-chrome

I have a small web app (Not Hosted, and maybe will not ever, just in development environment), being its key features AJAX requests over mongo database. Now i want my app being available as a Chrome App, and after checking the Google info about Importing Web Apps, I'm afraid that:

1.- Do  I need to completely re-estructure my app, since the server side component, based on Node.js and MongoDB cant be/is not easy to port into a Chrome App ?

2.- Is there any framework exclusively for Chrome Apps ? Are those really usefull more than the Chrome developer environment ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: the server side component wouldn't change, why should it?

Comment: Uhmm i am somewhat confused here. My Web App is not hosted yet, and maybe i will not ever, it is in development environment, and working ok. May i use what i have now to create the Chrome App ?

Comment: I must not understand the question or the design of your web app ... you mentioned a server side component, I assumed there was a **separate** client side component as well, which would be the component you'd want to change to a chrome app - and again, chrome app to me is chrome extension, but now I'm thinking you mean something to do with ChromeOS?

Comment: I apologize for the unclearly way to ask. I home new changes makes it better.